# How to check if rectilinear polygons intersect

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, geometry, polygon

I am trying to create a program in C to check if the lines of rectilinear polygon intersect each other at any point.
I only need simple rectilinear polygons that do not intersect at any point. It can be counter-clockwise or clockwise.

The direction values will be less than 10. NS direction must alternate with WE direction and vice versa.

The inputs being passed are in the form of direction from an input file such as; and also shown in the pictures:

> S 2  E 4 S 2 E 4 N 2 W 4 N 2 W 4

[image: EXAMPLE Images]

I tried to store points in a two-dimensional array with every point being checked as true, but I am unable to figure out how to move in case of counter and clockwise direction as the points could be N4 E6 or S4 W6. In such a case if I add when the value is N-4 (x,y) = (0,4) and subtract when S-4 (x,y) = (0,-4) that would fail when using it as index in array.

```
int arr[10][10];
int xPrime = 0, yPrime = 0;

bool checkContinuity(int y, const char * dir ){

    if(strcmp(dir, "S")==0){
        y = -y;
        cols = y;
        int j;
        for(j = cols; j >= 0; j--){
            if(arr[xPrime][j] == 1 && j != yPrime){
                return false;
            }
            arr[xPrime][j] = 1;             
            printf(" %d ", j);
        }
        yPrime -= y;
        if(yPrime < 0)
            yPrime = -yPrime;
    }
    else if(strcmp(dir, "W")==0){
        y = -y;
        cols = y;       
        int j;
        for(j = cols; j >= 0; j--){
            if(arr[j][yPrime] == 1 && j != xPrime && (j != 0 && yPrime != 0)){
                return false;
            }
            arr[j][yPrime] = 1;
            printf(" %d ", j);  
        }
        xPrime -= y;
        if(xPrime < 0)
            xPrime = -xPrime;
    }
    else if(strcmp(dir, "N")==0){
        cols = y;
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j <= cols; j++){
            if(arr[xPrime][j] == 1)
                return false;
            arr[xPrime][j] = 1; 
            printf(" %d ", j);
        }
        yPrime += y;
    }
    else if(strcmp(dir, "E")==0){
        cols = y;
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j <= cols; j++){
            if(arr[j][yPrime] == 1 && j != xPrime)
                return false;
            arr[j][yPrime] = 1;
            printf(" %d ", j);  
        }
        xPrime += y;
    }
    else
        return false;
            
    return true;
}
```

Comment: One way would be to pick the center of the array as the zero point. You can use negative indices, as long as they are within the bounds of the memory allocated.

Comment: Please provide the code you already have written. Not only will this show you have worked on this, but this will help us to provide an answer in your style of coding, making it more readable for you

Comment: You may iterate over the input string and accumulate given increments of coordinates to determine coordinates of each vertex. Then build a list of line segments in the given chain. Finally apply a line segments' intersection detection algorithm as described e.g. in https://www.ics.uci.edu/~goodrich/teach/geom/notes/LineSweep.pdf

Comment: @Ahsan Ali - First you have to make clear whether there are any limits for the input movements in any direction and if yes, what the limits are.

Comment: The limits are that the direction WE should alternate with SN

Comment: What is the range of shifts per step? Do you have any limit for the maximal length of the path?

Comment: no, but we can assume direction value < 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to store the actual polygon rather than all possible
points of the plane. We are then not restricted by the choice of the
point array (arr in your code). See this working example:

- the polygon is stored in the int-array P = {0, 0, x1, y1, x2, y2, ...}
- segments are two-point polygons. The function 'intersection' checks if
  two such segments Q and P intersect;
  if so, returns the intersection coordinates.
- It uses the helper function 'between' to ckeck if one number is between two others.
- the function 'next' calculates the next point of the polygon, assuming
  the input is provided as char-string (eg: "S2E4S2E4N2W4N2W4")
- In the function main we now loop over all segments, and check if they intersect with
  any previous one.

  Of course, the input should at some point be checked for sanity etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void
next(           const char *s,
                int *v          )
{
        v[2] = v[0]; 
        v[3] = v[1];
        int step = s[1] - '0';
        switch(s[0]) {
        case 'S': v[3] -= step; break;
        case 'N': v[3] += step; break;
        case 'W': v[2] -= step; break;
        case 'E': v[2] += step; break;
        }
}


int
between(        int x,
                int a,
                int b           )
{
        return a < b ? x >= a && x <= b : x >= b && x <= a;
}

int
intersection(   int *P,
                int *Q,
                int *R          )
{
        if(P[0] == P[2] && Q[1] == Q[3]){  // P vertical, Q horizontal (w.l.o.g.)
                if(between(P[0], Q[0], Q[2]) && between(Q[1], P[1], P[3])){
                        R[0] = P[0]; 
                        R[1] = Q[1]; 
                        return 1;
                } else
                        return 0;
        }else if(Q[0] == Q[2] && P[1] == P[3])
                return intersection(Q, P, R);
        else return 0;
}

int
main() {
        char *s = "S2E4S2E4N2W4N2W4";
        
        int n = strlen(s) / 2,                                  // number of steps
                *P = calloc((n + 1) * 2, sizeof(int)),          // polygon
                R[2];                                           // intersection
        if(!P) exit(137);
        
        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){
                next(s + 2 * k, P + 2 * k);
                for(int j = 0; j < k - 1; j++) {
                        if(intersection(P + k * 2, P + j * 2, R)) {
                                printf("Intersection at: %d, %d\n", R[0], R[1]);
                                exit(0);
                        }
                }
        }
        printf("No intersection\n");
}
```

Comment: It detects intersection in some cases but fails when the polygon starts from other than South in complete. e.g  "N4E6S4W6"

Comment: The program does not fail but reports the final closing step of the polygon as intersection. If you want to avoid this, then don't check the first and last segment against each other. This can be done by changing the condition in the inner loop to `if(!(k == n - 1 && j == 0) && intersection...`